# Question about Marking Duplicate Questions

Tags: discussion

I answered a question `Dec 16, 2011` : [How do you mysqldump specific table(s)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables/9309#9309)

Then, on `Feb 20, 2013`, I answered [Any option for mysqldump to ignore databases for backup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/any-option-for-mysqldump-to-ignore-databases-for-backup/35104#35104)

I just noticed that the older question was marked as duplicate on `Aug 28, 2015`.

## QUESTIONS

- Shouldn't the newer question be marked duplicate instead of the older one ?
- One question is about excluding tables and the other question about excluding databases. Should those be considered duplicate ?

Answer (score 6):

> Shouldn't the newer question be marked duplicate instead of the older one ?

The choice can be arbitrary - the moderator (or, in fact, the flaggers) could feasibly consider the newer question (or its answer(s)) to be better, more complete, more relevant, or any number of other qualities. I have had many flags on SO and meta go the opposite way I would have expected, too.

I can't answer for Paul's choice in this specific case, it may have been based on these subjective factors, or perhaps depended solely on any flags that existed to cause him to look in the first place. We are humans, after all, and there may not be a lot of scrutiny into whether the original flag pointed the duplicate in the wrong direction - I will confess that in a lot of cases I have not felt the need to do that much analysis - if one or more user said x is a duplicate of y, I will often stop at the analysis of the content, and short of examining which question was posted first, which has the answer with the most up-votes, which one had bounties, which one was by a user I don't like, etc. I just don't put a high priority on those secondary attributes, sorry.

> One question is about excluding tables and the other question about excluding databases. Should those be considered duplicate ?

Now that I would have a harder time answering, because I don't know MySQL well enough to know if they are questions that are "close enough" and could potentially be answered with the same solution. I also didn't investigate the other 8 answers on the older question to see if they use the same technique as the answer on the newer question; my research ended on happening to observe that there were 8 other answers in addition to yours.

Answer (score 4):

> Shouldn't the newer question be marked duplicate instead of the older one?

Usually, not but not always. If the newer answer is better, doesn't it make more sense for that to be the duplicate target? Assuming our goal is to point people to the best answer we have, rather than sticking rigidly to chronological order.

See the following on meta.SE:

[Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/194636)

> One question is about excluding tables and the other question about excluding databases. Should those be considered duplicate?

I thought so at the time, because the techniques seemed essentially the same, and the later answer seemed to be an improved method.

You didn't flag the question or even *vote to reopen* it, *but* assuming this meta question (which I've only just seen) means you disagree, I'm happy to defer to your MySQL expertise and reopen it.

If I misunderstood what you meant to ask, or if I have read between the lines incorrectly, please let me know.

For what it's worth, the closed-as-duplicate question and your answer continued to attract votes at about the same rate as they did before closure. Closing can be a precursor to deletion, but that is unlikely for such a popular question. It does prevent new answers though.